# ¿no sé porque me sale este error: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"?

Tags: java

Hice este código para resolver este ejercicio "Realizar un programa que permita realizar la preselección de los integrantes
del equipo de baloncesto, cuyo
requisito es tener más de 1.80 mts. de estatura y pesar menos de 100 Kg. Indicar si es apto o no lo es"

```
    public class ejercicio12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float estatura; 
        int peso;
        
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("============================================");
        System.out.println("PRESELECCION REQUISITOS A LOS ASPIRANTESA FORMAR PARTE DEL EQUIPO DE BALONCESTO");
        System.out.println("INGRESE ESTATURA:"); estatura=teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("INGRESE PESO:"); peso=teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("============================================");
        
        String men="NO APTO";
        if(estatura>1.80f && peso<100){
            men="APTO";
        }
```

y al recibir la primera entrada me sale este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
    at conditionals.ejercicio12.main(ejercicio12.java:24)
C:\Users\Casero\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Alguien seria tan amable de explicarme cual es el error que he cometido, soy novato en java.

Comment: Agrega los datos de entrada y los de salida que esperas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe al `IDE` que usas, seguramente está preparado para leer valores decimales con `,` en vez del `.`

Entonces existe 2 soluciones:

**Primera solucion**
Cuando quieras ingresar la estatura digita por ejemplo `1,85` en vez de `1.85`

**Segunda solución**
Cambia la linea de código

```
estatura=teclado.nextFloat();
```

Por esta linea de código

```
estatura=Float.parseFloat(teclado.nextLine());
```